# implicit return in a closure causing an error

Tags: swift

```
Error: Cannot convert the expression type (String, MyType) to ()
```

From the following code

```
Test(method: {[weak self] (message: String) in self?.callback(message)}, instance: self)
```

and if I add a return statement, it works, and the error goes away

```
Test(method: {[weak self] (message: String) in self?.callback(message); return}, instance: self)
```

Not sure how to handle the above without having to have the dummy return statement, any advise.

Here's my class Test

```
public class Test { 
    private var instance: AnyObject?
    private var method: ((message: String) -> ())?

    public init(method: (String -> ())?, instance: AnyObject) {

    }
 }
```

---

---

**Edit**

I've done a playground based minimalistic example (please copy paste for a test)

```
class Test {

    private var _method: ((String) -> ())?

    weak private var _instance: AnyObject?

    init(method: (String -> ())?, instance: AnyObject?) {
        _method = method
        _instance = instance
    }
}

class Another {

    func register() {
        //this doesn't need a return
        Test(method: {(message: String) in self.callback(message)}, instance: self)

        //this needs a return once I add [weak self]
        Test(method: { [weak self] (message: String) in self?.callback(message); return}, instance: self)
    }

    func callback(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: The initial call to `Test()` is missing an `instance` argument.  Also, the `Test()` expression is not scoped to include `self`.  Please show your actual code.

Comment: And what is a MyType? If you want real help, show real code. Otherwise, consider the problem solved and move on.

Comment: please see the edit section for a minimalistic example

Comment: I don't understand what more you want. The question is answered. Also in future please do not type fake code into Stack Overflow; always copy and paste actual reproducible code (as you did during your later pass).

Comment: but if you want to save more characters, you don't need to define the message string type: `(message: String) in` ==> `message in`  ;-)

Comment: setting it to `[unowned self]` removed the necessity to use `return`, however in this case I'm sure that self will always be available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure how to handle the above without having to have the dummy return statement, any advise.

You have solved the problem beautifully. Anonymous functions automatically use a one-line function body as a return value, so to prevent that from causing a type mismatch with the expected return type (Void) you have to add another line of code so that it is *not* a one-line function body. The dummy return statement, which itself returns Void, is a *great* way to handle it; I would just use that and move on. There are some snazzier workarounds but what you have is precisely what I would do.

EDIT: To understand the source of the type mismatch, try this:

```
struct Test {
    func voider() -> Void {}
}

let testMaybe = Optional(Test())
let result = testMaybe?.voider()
```

Now `result` is not a Void; it's an Optional wrapping a Void. That is what's happening to you; a Void is expected but your one-line anonymous function returns an Optional wrapping a Void. By adding another line that returns Void explicitly, you solved the problem.

Comment: And see my discussion of this matter in my new Swift tutorial here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions Skip down to the "Omission of the keyword `return`" section.

Comment: okay, I'd use but still a question, when my method as well as closure both have the return type of `(String) -> ()` or `Void` why there would be a conflict

Comment: and interestingly if I remove `[weak self]`, and `self?` the question mark, it works fine without the return statement

Comment: Because the `self?` causes the result to be wrapped in an Optional, which is the source of the type mismatch.

Comment: And if you remove `self?` then `callback()` is out-of-scope... until we see real code.

Comment: Added a little test code to my answer, so you can understand why saying `self?` causes the result type mismatch.

Comment: I'm understanding the optional Void part..., so it was `Void?`

Answer (score 0):

The implicit return is returning the result of your `callback()` method.  That return value conflicts with the closure's return value of `void`.  You thus need an explicit, if ugly, `return`.

Comment: the method signature as well as closure, both have `Void` return type, why would it conflict then